# JWT/LARAVEL 5.6 refresh expired token

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, jwt, laravel-5.6

I developed an API and I have a problem with the expiration of the token, and I try to find ways to refresh the tokens sent by API ,I use custom middleware,When the token is expired, the refreshed token is added to the response headers. The app just needs to search if the response has this, if so, update the saved token.I get

> {"code":103,"response":null}

my middleware

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\BadRequestHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\UnauthorizedHttpException;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenBlacklistedException;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Http\Middleware\BaseMiddleware;

class JwtRefresh extends BaseMiddleware {

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        try
        {
            if (! $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate() )
            {
                return response()->json([
                    'code'   => 101, // means auth error in the api,
                   'response' => null // nothing to show
                 ]);
            }
        }
        catch (TokenExpiredException $e)
        {
            // If the token is expired, then it will be refreshed and added to the headers
            try
            {
                $refreshed = JWTAuth::refresh(JWTAuth::getToken());
                $user = JWTAuth::setToken($refreshed)->toUser();
                header('Authorization: Bearer ' . $refreshed);
            }
            catch (JWTException $e)
            {
                return response()->json([
                    'code'   => 103, // means not refreshable
                   'response' => null // nothing to show
                 ]);
            }
        }
        catch (JWTException $e)
        {
            return response()->json([
                'code'   => 101, // means auth error in the api,
                   'response' => null // nothing to show
            ]);
        }

        // Login the user instance for global usage
        Auth::login($user, false);

        return  $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: You just asked this (at least almost identical title) before (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54627235/jwt-laravel-token-expired) Why don't you clarify problems in that question instead of asking again?

Comment: This another problem

Comment: then please use a title that really describes the problem instead of a generic "token expired". That a token expires is not a problem here, but the fact that you can't retrieve the refreshed token from the response seems to be the problem.

Comment: ok thank's a lot Sir :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to do this,

```
if ($expired) {
    try {
        $newToken = $this->auth->setRequest($request)
          ->parseToken()
          ->refresh();
        $user = $this->auth->authenticate($newToken);
    } catch (TokenExpiredException $e) {
        return $this->respond('tymon.jwt.expired', 'token_expired', $e->getStatusCode(), [$e]);
    } catch (JWTException $e) {
        return $this->respond('tymon.jwt.invalid', 'token_invalid', $e->getStatusCode(), [$e]);
    }
    // send the refreshed token back to the client
    $request->headers->set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' . $newToken);
}
```

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: where I put this?

Comment: In your catch where you are throwing **catch (TokenExpiredException $e) ... {**